# Wrapping echo for use in VimL

Tags: plugin-system, echo

I'm attempting to add some debugging functionality to a small vim plugin that I am working on. I'd like to wrap `echo` / `echom` in a way that allows me to turn off output if I want.

I've attempted to do this:

```
function! s:log(...)
  if (get(g:, 'my_plugin_debug_setting', 0))
    echom a:000
  end
endfunction

:call s:log('Debugging information')
```

but that just logs the list `['Debugging information']` (which makes sense, since i've just done the equivalent of `echo ['foo']`).

I've also attempted to use `call`: `:call call('echo', a:000)` but this doesn't work because echo is not a function.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my lh-vim-lib library plugin I provide a [framework for logging](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md) (among many other things) .

Unlike other frameworks (like maktaba) I don't try support several modes (error, warning, info, debug). Instead, I can choose to enable logs independently on each autoload plugin. Then, I can chose where the logs go (`:messages`, quickfix/loclist window, file, nowhere).

Otherwise, you could have used `:echom string(a:000)`, or even `join(a:000, ', ')` as long as the list only contains strings -- I had to do some recursive voodoo magic to obtain a nice result on any type of variables in my library.

Comment: Very interesting! It's unfortunate there isn't an easy way, but that's what I've come to expect from VimL :\